# How to set up the interpolation problem using ndimage.map_coordinates?

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, large-data

According to the documentation of `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates`,

> The array of coordinates is used to find, for each point in the
> output, the corresponding coordinates in the input. The value of the
> input at those coordinates is determined by spline interpolation of
> the requested order.
>
> The shape of the output is derived from that of the coordinate array
> by dropping the first axis. The values of the array along the first
> axis are the coordinates in the input array at which the output value
> is found.

I have a discrete 3-d function that is defined on a 3d grid *(t, x, y)*; on every point of this 3d grid, the function has a unique value unless it's value is zero.

I have another set of arrays in the form of a pandas dataframe with three columns, *t_new*, *x_new*, and *y_new*.

I would like to use `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` to interpolate the function in order to calculate its value on the new dataset presented in the said dataframe.

Since I am getting the following error message, I am sure I am not setting up the map_coordinates correctly:

```
File "D:\Users\username\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\ndimage\interpolation.py", line 437, in map_coordinates

raise RuntimeError('invalid shape for coordinate array')
```

Here is my definition of the interpolation function:

```
from scipy.ndimage import map_coordinates



def interpolator_3d(df, func_values):

    # The coordinates at which input is evaluated

    coordinates = df[['t_new', 'x_new', 'y_new']].values.T    # (3, 1273)

    # list of input array [[t0, x0, y0, value0], [t1, x1, y1, value1], ...]

    input_arr = func_values                                 # (1780020000, 4)

    return map_coordinates(input_arr, coordinates)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are at least two issues with how you are using `map_coordinates`. Keep in mind that this function was designed for image resampling.

1. If you have a 3d-function the array `input_arr` should be 3-dimensional. `map_coordinates` will use the indices as `t`, `x` and `y` coordinates. The value `v` of the function has to be stored at each respective position. If your original function has another base grid, then you have to normalize everything accordingly to the arrays indices before and after. This requires an equidistant grid as input.
2. The `coordinates` have to be an array e.g. of the form `[[t_new_0, t_new_1, ...], [x_new_0, x_new_1 ...], [y_new_0, y_new_1, ...]]`. The result will be a list of interpolated samples `[[v_new_0, v_new_1, ...]]`. Generally, if `input_array` is `n`-dimensional, `coordinates` has to be a list that contains `n` arrays of same shape `S`. The result will be a list of arrays of shape `S`.

Example with `n`=3 dimensions and 5 samples to interpolate in a 1-dimensional shape:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import ndimage

a = np.arange(64.).reshape((4, 4, 4))
print(a)

out = ndimage.map_coordinates(a, [
  [0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5], [2.0, 1.9, 1.8, 1.7, 1.6]
])
print(out)
```

Output:

```
[[[ 0.  1.  2.  3.]
  [ 4.  5.  6.  7.]
  [ 8.  9. 10. 11.]
  [12. 13. 14. 15.]]
 [[16. 17. 18. 19.]
  [20. 21. 22. 23.]
  [24. 25. 26. 27.]
  [28. 29. 30. 31.]]
 [[32. 33. 34. 35.]
  [36. 37. 38. 39.]
  [40. 41. 42. 43.]
  [44. 45. 46. 47.]]
 [[48. 49. 50. 51.]
  [52. 53. 54. 55.]
  [56. 57. 58. 59.]
  [60. 61. 62. 63.]]]

[ 7.6688, 18.148 , 26.3424, 34.6304, 45.3904]
```

**Update:**

That means, if your `input_array` has the form `[[t0, x0, y0, value0], [t1, x1, y1, value1], ...]` with length `1780020000 = 19778 * 500 * 180` it has to be transformed accordingly to an array of shape `(19778, 500, 180)`:

```
t_max, x_max, y_max, _ = np.max(func_values, axis=0).astype(int) + 1  # 19778, 500, 180
input_arr = np.zeros((t_max, x_max, y_max), dtype=float)

for t, x, y, v in func_values:
  input_arr[int(t), int(x), int(y)] = v
```

Comment: Thank you Markus, what would be the sample shape in my problem?

Comment: @Ash, please add a small part of `func_values` to your question. I.e can you tell us minimum, maximum and step of the function grid’s base coordinates? Are they equidistant?

Comment: I will post the func_values tomorrow as soon as I have access to it but here are some general info I have in regards to the components of 3d grid: the t component index of the 3d function goes from 0 to 19777, the x component index goes from 0 to 499 and the y component index goes from 0 to 179. The values of the function on this 3d grid are either very small positive real numbers or 0.

Comment: @Ash, thank you for adding the ranges. I've updated my answer with some code that should transform your `func_values` to the `input_arr` that we need for `map_coordinates`. Please check with your data!

Comment: sorry that I am not able to post the data in here due to its confidential nature but the update to the answer should be working. I am accepting this as the answer.

Comment: If I had any follow-up question after applying your recommendation, I will ask you. Thank You,